# extra features adds if date goes missing from the url

Tags: php, regex, web-services, web

I have got a website of my service center.
people before coming to my center register about their service they need an book the dates.

the problem is when the whole procedure is done in a proper manner then there is no issue in my website
i.e.: Selection of dates comes 1st, followed by selection of service station, then follows the services they need for their car,.
and the url generated is something like:

```
www.example.com/servicedate=139475?&stationname?&servicename
```

but if any how the date thing gose missing from the url
I mean if "/servicedate=139475 " like `www.exmple.com/stationname=&servicename` goes missing from the url, the page shows normal layout but it starts showing extra services which is not to be showed on that date.

How to solve this problem?

Comment: add some code and show us how this url is generated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this will suffice ?

```
if(!isset($_GET['stationname']))
{
echo "Data Missing...";
exit;
}
else
{
// ... your normal code...
}
```

Do like this for your other variables..

Comment: hello sir,  I tried adding this into my codes , but it did not work, was showing some other error and the also vanished..

Comment: `but it did not work, was showing some other error and the also vanished` Doesn't really help. Can you post what you have tried on your question.?